# lit-element : Bind to a boolean attribute : Issue with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, lit-element, lit-html

I'm using Bind to boolean attribute as mentioned in the documentation https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/templates  as given below.

This works fine in Chrome but for some reason not working in Internet Explorer 11. It always behaves as falsy. and doesn't add the attribute.

Is there a known issue or I'm missing something.

To simulate the scenario :

Create two custom-elements, parent and child element. Pass boolean attribute through child element boolean property and use that property to make enable disable a textbox.

Parent element

```
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright (c) 2019 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
 * This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at
 * http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
 * The complete set of authors may be found at
 * http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
 * The complete set of contributors may be found at
 * http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
 * Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
 * subject to an additional IP rights grant found at
 * http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
 */

import {LitElement, html, customElement, property, css} from 'lit-element';
import './my-other-element';

/**
 * An example element.
 *
 * @slot - This element has a slot
 * @csspart button - The button
 */
@customElement('my-element')
export class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`
    :host {
      display: block;
      border: solid 1px gray;
      padding: 16px;
      max-width: 800px;
    }
  `;

  /**
   * The name to say "Hello" to.
   */
  @property()
  name = 'World';

  /**
   * The number of times the button has been clicked.
   */
  @property({type: Number})
  count = 0;

  render() {
    return html`
      <h1>Hello, ${this.name}!</h1>
      <button @click=${this._onClick} part="button">
        Click Count: ${this.count}
      </button>
      <my-other-element ?makeDisable="${true}"></my-other-element>
      <slot></slot>
    `;
  }

  private _onClick() {
    this.count++;
  }

  foo(): string {
    return 'foo';
  }
}

declare global {
  interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    'my-element': MyElement;
  }
}
```

Child element

```
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright (c) 2019 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
 * This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at
 * http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
 * The complete set of authors may be found at
 * http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
 * The complete set of contributors may be found at
 * http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
 * Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
 * subject to an additional IP rights grant found at
 * http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
 */

import {LitElement, html, customElement, property, css} from 'lit-element';

/**
 * An example element.
 *
 * @slot - This element has a slot
 * @csspart button - The button
 */
@customElement('my-other-element')
export class MyOtherElement extends LitElement {
  @property({type: Boolean}) makeDisable = false;
  static styles = css`
    :host {
      display: block;
      border: solid 1px gray;
      padding: 16px;
      max-width: 800px;
    }
  `;

  /**
   * The name to say "Hello" to.
   */
  @property()
  name = 'World';

  /**
   * The number of times the button has been clicked.
   */
  @property({type: Number})
  count = 0;

  render() {
    return html`
      <input type="text" ?disabled="${this.makeDisable}" value="testing" />
      <slot></slot>
    `;
  }

  foo(): string {
    return 'foo';
  }
}

declare global {
  interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    'my-other-element': MyOtherElement;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rohit Singh, According to the [LitEelement Getting Started](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/start) document, I have installed the [TypeScript starter project](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/lit-element-starter-ts/archive/master.zip) and test the code `<input type="text" ?disabled="${this.prop3}">` on the application, the  bind of the boolean attribute works well. The screenshot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2VlO.png). You can download the starter project and test it. Besides, when using F12 to check the resource, it seems that it will add polyfill to handle the `?`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @ZhiLv   This is working as expected didn't check on the simplest example. But to simulate the actual scenario, I'm passing boolean value through property to the child element (custom element). There its not working in Internet explorer. I'll modify my question though.

Comment: It seems that in IE the boolean value is always controlled by the value of `makeDisable` in child element. You can only set `makeDisable = true` in child element if you want to disable the textbox. Besides, I find that if I set `makeDisable = true` in child element and set `?makeDisable="${false}"` in parent element, the textbox is still disabled in both Chrome and IE. Should the textbox be enabled in this situation? So I think the best way is just to set the boolean in child element.

Answer (score 2):

In lit-element if you add a boolean value in constructor and if it is true, you cannot set false for that.

[case](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/948)

I have tried it like `<input type="text" .disabled="${false}">` and it works.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.. will verify